# Getting prime by changing 2 digits

Tags: nt.number-theory, analytic-number-theory, prime-numbers

I just got a result, an exercise of Tenenbaum's book that one cannot get a prime from arbitrary natural number $n$ by changing only one digit of its decimal expansion. For example, you cannot get prime by changing only one digit of $200$ since you need to change the last digit, but $201, 203, 207, 209$ are composite. Another proof is one can use prime number theorem by assuming we can change only one digit of $10k, k\in \mathbb{N}$ to get prime, but this means
\begin{align*}
\pi(x)\geq \sum_{k\leq x/10}1\geq \lfloor x/10 \rfloor
\end{align*}
since there will always be prime in $[10k,10k+9]$
which contradicts prime number theorem. My question is, can we get prime by changing exactly two digits of $n$ for arbitrary $n \geq 100$? One can change the first digit to $0$ but not adding digit, for example, we can change $123$ to $23$ but not $1123$.

Note : I posted this also in Math SE https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4487279/getting-prime-by-changing-2-digits?noredirect=1#comment9418905_4487279, but I think it is suitable to post it here.

Comment: The prime number theorem is an overkill. It is elementary (high school exercise) that $\pi(x)<x/10$ for large $x$, and in fact it is also elementary that $\pi(x)/x$ tends to zero as $x\to\infty$. BTW I suspect that there are infinitely many numbers divisible by $10$ in which you need to change more than $2$ digits to get a prime. This is similar to the phenomenon that there are arbitrary large $x$ such that $[x,x+1000\log x]$ contains no prime.

Comment: @GHfromMO yes I agree, but I think it might inspire some idea to attack this problem. I also suspected that fact but after trying several computations I haven't found any single example

Comment: @LaurencePW: And can you find an $x$ such that $[x+1000\log x]$ contains no prime? In general, "empirical verification" of prime number phenomena is notoriously hard, because the distribution of primes is rather tricky.

Comment: @GHfromMO not yet

Comment: https://people.math.sc.edu/filaseta/papers/FKNSpaper0808.pdf conjectures the following: "We turn to some open questions. [Four questions stated, followed by:] Do there exist infinitely many composite numbers N that remain composite when any two digits (not necessarily consecutive) are changed (or inserted)? Based on heuristics, we conjecture that the answers to all of the above questions except the last is in the affirmative."

Comment: That said, by making the final digit 0 or 5 as Timothy Chow suggests, it seems to me that the methods of that paper (which are precisely covering-congruence techniques) resolve the question in the other direction.  In other words, it seems to me that there are infinitely many composite numbers so that changing up to any two digits keeps the number composite.

Answer (score 5):

This is not a complete answer, but should point in the right direction. A [delicate prime](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delicate_prime) is a prime number with the property that replacing any one of its digits (not counting leading zeros) with any other digit always results in a composite number.  For example, 294001 is a delicate prime.

Finding a counterexample to your question (i.e., a composite number such that changing any two digits results in a composite number) is closely related to finding delicate primes.  Basically, we want a number $n$ ending in zero such that $n+1$, $n+3$, $n+7$, and $n+9$ all have the delicate prime property, *except* that $n+1$, $n+3$, $n+7$, and $n+9$ themselves need not be prime.  If there is such a thing, then I would expect that covering-congruence techniques (similar to those used to construct delicate primes) could be used to prove its existence.

Comment: As you say, this seems like a (useful!) comment, not an answer.

Comment: @LSpice It's a bit long for a comment, though.